# AngularJS 'unknown provider' after minification (ng-strict-di being activated)

Tags: angularjs, minify, google-closure-compiler, dependency-resolver

I first concatenate all my js files via `grunt-contrib-concat` grunt task. With this one everything worked fine (no minification).

I'm trying to switch to Google's Closure Compiler so I can minify it and add source maps, to start I'm using this options: `--compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY` and `--formatting=pretty_print` and I'm passing files in the same order as I did before with the grunt task so i should have a first output similar to what I've got before.

NOTE: Thanks to some sublime text magic and a diff checker, I have been able to check that both of my final generated files got all the same controllers/services in the EXACT SAME order.

All my controllers weren't using the annotation syntaxe (dependencies being declared as string before controller) so i used ng-annotate and [this script](https://coderwall.com/p/kyu9qw/use-ng-annotate-for-all-files-in-directory-and-its-contents-recursively) to solve this problem.

Now all my files are ready for minification. To be sure about that I even declared `ng-strict-di` on my app and temporarly switch back to the previous concatenation system. It works perfect and fails if I deliberatly put a typo in my controllers name.

So from this I thought Closure Compiler should have worked like a charm... But no, I'm facing an `Unknown Provider` error when angular try to inject my first service inside my `app.run()` function. (The `.config()` is executed well as I've no custom dependencies here as well as the three first dependencies of the  `.run()`. It really is MY personnaly implemented dependencie that fail.)

Did someone already face a similar issue ? Any idea what could cause this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I found out that closure compiler do not import files the same way as the grunt task I used to use.

When using the notation `src/js/controllers/**/*.js` I excpected it to import the files directly inside my controller folder but it didn't.

I was sure to have checked this but I certainly made a mistake and compare the old file with the old file instead of the new one; that's why I thought I got all my dependencies in the file and in same order when checking...